# How to deselect a marker in google maps swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im trying to deselect a maker that I selected using `mapView.selectedMarker = locationMarker`. When I use mapView.clear() my map is clear but when I tap to open the marker at the same location I have to tap twice because I never did deselect the marker. I can not find the function that deselect the marker.

Answer (score 2):

According to doc written at `GMSMapView`'s property `selectedMarker`, it says

[image]

You just need to write `mapView.selectedMarker = nil` to deselect the selected marker.